# Resetting the scene in processing by pressing any button

Tags: processing

Does anyone know how to reset the scene when any key is pressed after the animation is done. I want to use this method:

```
void keyPressed()
{
  //what code? 
}
```

But I do not know what code to put inside to make the scene reset. Can someone help?

Comment: Please take a look at the [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) docs...  we'll need much more information before we can help you with this question

Answer (score 2):

You have to store your "scene" in variables. To reset your scene, you simply reset those variables.

Here's a simple example that shows a moving ball that resets when you press a key:

```
int ballX = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 100);
}

void keyPressed() {
  ballX = 0;
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  ballX++;
  ellipse(ballX, height/2, 10, 10);
}
```

Your real "scene" probably has more than one variable, but the idea is the same. Store your "scene" in variables, and then reset those variables when you want to reset the scene.